# Yasnipped expand also after character

Tags: yasnippet

I am trying to write a snipped mode for writing subscripts in LaTeX:

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: sub
# key: _
# --
_{\text{$1}}$0
```

If I type just `_ + TAB` it expands correctly  as expencted. But if there is a character before `_`, it doesn't expand at all. However this is the case where I need it. For example

`x_ + TAB` should expand to  `x_{\text{}}`

If this is not possible in `yasnipped`, what would be the best way to get exactly this in emacs?

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is slightly incorrect, imho. Yasnippet expands *symbols*, that is, frankly speaking, something surrounded with white space.

How about this:

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: sub
# key: sub
# --
${1:symbol}_\{\text\{${2:subscript}\}\}
```

In other words, you're trying to append something to separate symbol, while you could use any short symbol just to insert necessary template and then fill it out -- works just as well.

---

Of course if you really-really want to do it your way, it's possible:

- write around advice for `yas-expand`;
- see if word immediately before point ends with a `_`;
- magically find your snippet and manually feed it to internal functions of Yasnippet, trigger snippet expansion;
- if word before point is not magic, call real `yas-exapand`;
- now it should work, but you want to use conventional approach at this point (or you're ready to invent another template system for Emacs, that *does it right for you*).

Comment: Thanks. I don't really understand the second approach. If it's just a few lines of code, please just post it. If not, is there another (almost) ready to use solution in emacs which does exactly what I want?

Comment: @student, As far as I know, no. Writing such a hack takes some time (maybe hour) of exploring things, I just don't feel it's right way to do it, so I posted plan of second approach just as an example that it's possible.