# How to expand yas-snippet, when trigger-key is part of a word?

Tags: yasnippet

I have following yas-snippet (for python-mode):

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: .s-np_array_shape
# key: .s
# --
.shape
```

And now, `.s` <kbd>Tab</kbd> gives `.shape` as expected.

**What I want**:

This doesn't expand if there is another character right before `.s`.

In other words, I want to expand this snippet from `a.s` <kbd>Tab</kbd> to `a.shape`.

Is it possible to achieve this?

---

**Update**:

- I found same question asked some years ago [link](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13938/yasnipped-expand-also-after-character): No exact answer I'm looking for.
- also found this [issue](https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet/issues/988) on github. Some people were working on expanding with **regex**, but it seems like abandoned.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT in response to comment

In order not to break your 'multi-entry snippets', you could create a separate command to expand keys starting with a dot using the extended `yas-key-syntaxes` list.

For that, do not add the `#'yas-try-key-from-dot` to `yas-key-syntaxes` using `add-to-list`, but instead set the `yas-key-syntaxes` locally within your custom command as follows:

```lisp
(defun my-yas-expand ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((yas-key-syntaxes (append yas-key-syntaxes '(yas-try-key-from-dot))))
    (yas-expand)))
```

(so you should still use/evaluate `yas-try-key-from-dot`).

Now, you can use `M-x my-yas-expand` for expanding keys that start with a dot (and you can create an 'alternative' keybinding for it).

END EDIT

Is it really necessary to use the dot in the key (i.e. are you already using the key `s` without the dot)? Otherwise, it might be easier to just type the dot and then expand 'shape'. Then expansion should already work when the trigger key is right after the dot.

If the dot really needs to be included in the key, then you could add a custom function to `yas-key-syntaxes` as follows (the following function is inspired by `yas-try-key-from-whitespace`):

```lisp
(defun yas-try-key-from-dot (_start-point)
  "As `yas-key-syntaxes' element, look for dot delimited key."
  (skip-chars-backward "^.")
  (backward-char))

(add-to-list 'yas-key-syntaxes #'yas-try-key-from-dot t)
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `add-to-list`? `append` won't update `yas-key-syntaxes`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion (we could use add-to-list, but we should make sure to add it to the end of the list). However, I deleted that original answer immediately after creating it. But to rewrite the answer, I had to undelete that old answer first, and you could see it while I was writing the corrected answer (I consider that a SE bug). So you were writing the comment while I was correcting the answer. Anyway, that answer was wrong, and the string `w` is already in that list by default.

Comment: yes I saw it updated a few seconds after I commented (: , does `add-to-list` not have an `append` flag  (and wouldn't add it if it was already present - though not that helpful in this situation) ? Anyway, the answer works a treat a for me, thanks.

Comment: Yes, you're right, and indeed it is nicer and probably a better option to use here. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have zero knowledge on e-lisp. So this is very helpful. This works for `.s` type snippets. However, after loading this code some of my multi-entry snippets working not correctly. In details, `yas-next-field` no longer jumps to next field.

Comment: On the part that not including `.` in the key, I didn't know just `s` will expand after `.`. Previously I tried to expand `_` to `_{}` in latex, and it didn't expand if there is a character before `_`.  From that, I got impression that snippets doesn't expand if there char before the key.  I apologize for this. However, There is some appeal to expand with  dot (`.s`) for tidying purposes.

Comment: Ah, a pity that it breaks the 'multi-entry' snippets. Well, maybe the solution without the dot in the key works for you then. If not, then let us know here. In that case, we could make separate functions/keybindings, one that uses the original value of `yas-key-syntaxes` and another one that uses the one with that custom function added.

Comment: @dalanicolai , if it's not difficult, could you make that please. Having `.` in key, helps me to declutter my snippets.

Comment: @Garid Not sure if you have seen it, but I have updated the answer...

Comment: @dalanicolai thanks mate, I've been just seen it